# Why doesn't the Ministerio use future technology?

Tags: the-ministry-of-time

In *The Ministry of Time* (*El Ministerio del Tiempo*), the eponymous Ministry deals with time travel. We've seen that the Ministry doesn't limit itself to contemporaneous technology: for instance, the head of the Ministry from, I think, the 1800s had a fairly-modern telephone with which he was able to call the modern Ministry. And, of course, outside of the Ministry itself, certainly they are willing to provide modern technology to their operatives for their missions, such as guns and computers. However, we don't seem to see anything more advanced than the modern day.

Obviously, out of universe, predicting future technology and developments is difficult, and would distract from a show that is largely historical. But in-universe, is there a reason that the ministry is restricted to 21st-century technology?

Comment: In the series, it is stated that the doors can't be used to travel to the future. Though, this is a direct contradiction with the last episode, where they do travel to the 2019 (the future, since the series are in 2017).

Comment: @Roberto, you should make that an answer.

Comment: @Dima Let me see if I can find the episode where this is stated and I'll post an answer with the sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**They can't travel to the future.**

Apparently, the time doors can't be used to travel to the future. This is because the past and the present exist, but the future doesn't exist yet. Thus, there aren’t  doors that connect to the future.

> La respuesta la da Jaime Blanch en su papel de máximo responsable del
>   Ministerio: no se puede viajar al futuro. Las puertas se van abriendo
>   hacia el pasado a medida que el reloj avanza. “El tiempo es el que es
>   y el que fue”.
>
> <sub>https://blogs.20minutos.es/ciencias-mixtas/2015/03/04/la-ciencia-del-tiempo-en-el-ministerio-del-tiempo/</sub>

Translated to english, the quote would be something like:

> The answer is provided by Jaime Blanch as the head of the *Ministry of Time*: it is not possible to travel to the future. The doors open towards the past as the clock goes on. "The time is as it is and as it was".

An alternative translation to the quote would be:

> "Time is what was and what is"

I can't find the exact episode where he says that, though. I'd have to rewatch the series to find it.

---

However, in the last episode of the third season, this rule is broken, because the team travels to the 2019 (while the series are based in the 2017). This is sort of explained by stating that *the Book of Doors* (Libro de las Puertas) contained the secret to travel to the future, and Pacino unveiled it to save the *Ministry of Time*.

I guess we'll have to wait for the 4th season (it is expected to be released in 2020) to find out more details about this contradiction.

Comment: But, ah, the future from the perspective of whom? From the perspective of the 1800s Ministerio head, isn't the patrulla coming from the future? As is the technology that he uses: phones, cameras, etc. Let us say that they can't go to their own future: what prevents people from the future ministries from opening a door just as they do?

Comment: Also wrt to the quote do you think it is more like "Time is what was and what is"? (I.e. time is the past and the present)?

Comment: @Adamant The phrase hints that the present is the 2015 (the date where everything happens), and there is no future beyond that year (yet). Just imagine you're drawing a line, you can travel backwards that line or back to the point where you left but you can't travel further until it is draw. And yeah, your quote translation is correct.

Comment: @Adamant to use other words, since creation doors allow to travel to the past and return to the present with objects and people. So in 1800 you can travel to 1600 but not to 2015; it is yet to exist. So the 1800 Ministerio will see 2010s patrols visiting their past and returning to their present, but not traveling to the future.

Comment: @Seretba Yes and no. Since there's a 2015 (the present), people from 1800 can use the doors to travel to the present (2015). But 200 years ago, there wasn't a 2015 (because it was yet to happen) and people could only travel to the 1819 or before.

Comment: I am 99% sure that that does not make any sense, but if that is the answer they are giving, this is a correct answer.

Comment: For what it is worth, in the first episode of the second season they speak of the Ministerio of 2019 as *el ultimo y principal ministerio*, which (to me at least) seems to suggest that it is somehow different from all the others, and that there *is* no Ministerio, say, 200 years in the future.

Comment: The one of 2017, I mean. Not that it should make a difference.